GEE export tasks sometimes fail because they can't access asset that exists
Using GEE, I have to send many concurrent tasks that perform simple summing reduce over raster maps that i uploaded as assets.
The code combines 37 image assets into a single image collection, then apply a reduce over some geometries.
Most of the time the tasks run smoothly and complete, but sometimes a task fails because of the error:

Error: Image.load: Image asset not found (does not exist or caller does not have access). (Error code: 3)

However, the Image asset does exists, and many tasks complete without a problem.
What can cause some tasks to fail on this error? And how can this be fixed? This happens rarely, but even 1 or 2 times really disrupts my workflow.
